# Objective-C/Cocoa: Detect all keypresses

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keypress

Is it possible to run a method every time the user presses a key. Basically I want to run a sound like on the iPhone or iPad when a key is pressed. **I do not want to detect key presses in my window or in a certain control, I want to detect ALL presses (such as when they are typing in Safari or something.** I do not need to know what the key is.

Thanks

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but there are already existing apps that do this: http://sustworks.com/site/prod_keyclick_overview.html (It is however payware)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `CGEventTapCreate` documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html

Or use NSEvents `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsevent_Class/Reference/Reference.html

NSEvent Example:

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSKeyDownMask) handler:^(NSEvent *event){
    [self keyWasPressedFunction: event];
    //Or just put your code here
}];
```

I would say NSEvents are easier...

Note:

For security reasons, Apple requires you have "Enable access for assistive devices" turned on in System Preferences, in order to use ether of the above methods.

Comment: @Oliver: Okay added NSEvent example, CGEventTaps are much more complex, and not necessary for what your trying to do...

Answer (score 3):

You can get pretty close with a Quartz event tap, but some keypresses aren't detectable even with one for the sake of security.

If you tell us the broader goal you have in mind, we can suggest alternatives. Are you trying to establish a global hotkey for your app? Are you writing a keylogger or malware? What?

Comment: All i'm trying to do is make an app that plays the iPad or iPhone key tap noise when ever they press a key.

Comment: Then you should look at event taps. Again, not all keypresses can be detected for security reasons (e.g. you can't get keypress events when a password field is being used.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSEvents addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`

In `applicationDidFinishLaunching` add the following code, build & go!

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSKeyDownMask) handler:^(NSEvent *event){
NSLog(@"%@", event.characters);
}];
```

Apple requires you have "Enable access for assistive devices" turned on in System Preferences.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsevent_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Don't forget to deallocate the monitor in the ``applicationWillClose`` function