# Keyboard event from anywhere

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to build an app that does something when the user pushes a (keyboard) button, no matter what app is currently running in the front. (Like "CheatSheet")
How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369008/objective-c-cocoa-detect-all-keypresses

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean keylogging input from other apps? If so, this is not possible due to obvious security concerns.

Comment: It most certainly is possible.

Comment: As an interface provided by apple, or an exploitable security hole?

Comment: No! The key 'F6' for example, has almost no use. So I want that my app will recognize when the user clicks it. It won't effect any app but the app I want to build.